# Connecting to Amazon VPC instances via WinSCP

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, winscp, amazon-vpc

I am looking for a way to connect to an Amazon VPC EC2 instance from WinSCP. I am able to connect to it via PuTTY by SSHing to the NAT server and then ssh to the private instance using its private IP.

However, I am not sure how to do this in WinSCP to transfer files from/to the instance.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [NAT server](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html) as an SSH tunnel.

- Either set up a port forwarding in your PuTTY instance and connect WinSCP via that forwarding.
- Or use a native tunneling support in WinSCP.

For details on both approaches, see WinSCP guide to [connecting to SFTP server which can be accessed via another server only](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_tunnel).

Also mentioned in WinSCP guide to [Connecting securely to Amazon EC2 server with SFTP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_amazon_ec2#vpc).

Comment: I was using the tunneling support however I switched the ips of the two servers. Thanks